# Filebeat overwrites data view (index pattern) when importing dashboards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I have filebeat & kibana, and I'm using kibana dashboard auto-creating with filebeat.

Also, I need to apply some field transforms in data view (index pattern).

But when filebeat creates dashboards, it overwrites data view with defaults.

I need both of features: dashboards and data view (index pattern) auto-creation, and having transforms for some of the fields.

EDIT: Ideally, I would like to supply these transforms settings along with my custom filebeat module.

More detailed:

Among fields there are few to which I need to apply transforms in kibana data view (index pattern).

For example:

- One of my fields contains full java class name and I need to apply "short dots" string transform for it.
- Other field is log level name, and I need to colorize it (i.e. red for "ERROR").
  "My" fields are from my filebeat module.

I'm able to apply these transfroms in data view settings by hand (in web or by importing index pattern via API).

But when filebeat (re)starts, it overwrites data view (index pattern) with defaults.
I would like to have both abilities:

- To auto-create dashboards with filebeat.
- To apply field transforms in data view (index pattern).
  But not to overwrite them occidentially if (or when) filebeat restarts.

Is it possible?

The only way I see now is:

- Start filebeat once to just import dashboard and exit.
- Patch data view (export, make needed changes, import; or just import a fixed data view version).
- Start filebeat, this time with dashboard import disabled.
  But this way seems to be overhead. May be I don't see some better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. Disable all `setup.*` parameters in `filebeat.yml`.
2. Execute manually and only once:

```
filebeat setup -e
```

It will install dashboards, data views, etc. related to the list of modules you have configured in `filebeat.yml`.